# Using LLMs for structured data?

Tags: machine-learning, language-model, structured-data

I've been trying to work with structured data in language models, and it's proving to be quite challenging. I'm confident that with Langchain, I should be able to solve the problem, but I'm not entirely sure which path to take among all the options the library offers.

My issue is as follows: I have data in the form of dictionaries regarding a series of products, for example, laptops. The data looks like this:

{Identifier 1: X, Identifier 2: Y, Value name: Z}

(Several successive dictionaries like this.)

I want to use this series of dictionaries as context, then feed a different dictionary into the Language Model, and have it tell me if the 'Value name' makes sense given Identifiers 1 and 2. An example would be Identifier 1: laptops, Identifier 2: brand, Value name: Lenovo. In this case, it should return affirmative since Lenovo makes sense as a brand. However, if I input 'oranges,' it should return negative.

Any ideas on which library I could use to tackle this problem?